# How long may parameters in a get request be?

Tags: http, url, rest, get, web-standards

I am currently programming an API that gets passed data via get parameters so I was wondering if the total length of the URL or of the parameters value is limited in best practice or by the protocol.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, 2K is the most you can rely on in a cross-browser fashion, but if you drop support for IE 8 and below, you can get to like 64K.

Although I feel I need to question your need to know this, anything over say.. 100  characters would best be handled through a POST request instead of a GET.

Comment: I am quoting your link "Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters will not work in the most popular web browser.", thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: My opinion, but long URLs are a sign of code smell. Not a problem in an of itself, but often a symptom of a more fundamental problem.

Comment: However, if you're trying to be RESTful, a POST shouldn't be executed if it doesn't change a resource on the server.

Comment: You mean drop support for every browser.
The limit in Internet Explorer and Safari is about 2 KB, in Opera about 4 KB and in Firefox about 8 KB. We may thus assume that 8 KB is the maximum possible length and that 2 KB is a more affordable length to rely on at the server side and that 255 bytes is the safest length to assume that the entire URL will come in.
64k is definitely not something that works in any to me known browser.

Comment: "64k is definitely not something that works in any to me known browser" -- well, good thing you don't know much then, because [Chrome has support for 2MB URLs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/security/url_display_guidelines/url_display_guidelines.md#URL-Length) (and displays up to 32k).

Comment: @BedaSchmid Also I don't know where you get your fake data from, but [Firefox has been proven to work with at least 100k URLs and claims it has no arbitrary limit](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/924935).

Comment: I tested. It stopped handling GET request at around 8000 characters with "request uri exceeds limits" or similar message. Then I googled. Came here. Saw the reply, googled more and found lots of different statements. Tested again on Safari and confirmed again the limits are relatively low, above IE (2+k) but below 10K. That was get request to local server, not online URL of a remote server.

Comment: For those who reflexively say "use POST"; those are generally not cacheable and thus not appropriate for all situations.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add the canonical reference... from the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), in section 3.2.1:

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
>      a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
>      serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
>      provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
>      SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
>      than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> ```
> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>   above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>   implementations might not properly support these lengths.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official limit, so its at the mercy of the different browsers.