# GET request with long query parameters

Tags: post, get, query-string

I have any API which exports .xlsx data.

The conditions for SQL need 2 ids and I also need to pass the column name/s. I pass the ids via query-parameters along with the column names in a GET request, the column names can be 1 or 10 or 100 depending on the data collected. So it may become a long URL.

Do I modify it to a POST and send the columns in the body or should I send it the way I am right now?

Answer (score 0):

If there is possiblity of URL taking more than 100 characters, you can better go for POST request rather than GET.

you can refer to a similar question asked here:
[How long may parameters in a get request be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205479/how-long-may-parameters-in-a-get-request-be)